# Problem with data transformation ahead of predictive model - Name 'articles' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, naivebayes

I am running my Naive Bayes model to categorize text as relevant or not. I am uploading a dataset containing text to be scanned - but when I try to transform the data (tokenize and lemmetize) I get the attached error - name articles is not defined.

This is the code:

```
dff['text'] = dff['text'].str.lower()
dff = dff.drop_duplicates('text')

start_time = time.time()

X = dff.text
X_test_vect = tf_vectorizer.transform(X)
y_pred = nb.predict(X_test_vect)
y_pred_prob = nb.predict_proba(X_test_vect)[:, 1]
y_pred

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Unfortunately, I cannot share the predictive model and I do not think the data itself would be useful to share.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message made it very clear. You did not define `articles`

Take a look at variable pass to the function,

```py
def __call__(self,articlegs):
```

You passed the `articlegs` variable and try to use `articles` inside the function caused the issue. keep the variable name the same would fix. You may try below,

```py
def __call__(self,articles):
```

Comment: thanks! apologies, I am not too familiar with the process - the variable that I pass is dff.text - there is no articlegs variable in my dataset. Where did that come from?